# Ampliar datagridview proporcionalmente

Tags: vb.net

Como puedo hacer para agrandar un datagridview proporcionalmente cuando se amplíe el formulario en el que se encuentra?
Pongo ejemplos:

Sin ampliar

[image: Sin ampliar:]

Ampliada
[image: Ampliado:]

Sería la diferencia, sin ampliar el datagridview es más pequeño que ampliado.
Cuando yo maximizo el programa no se amplía y entonces el datagridview queda en el mismo tamaño y lo que quiero es que se haga más grande, igual que el Form1.

Muchas gracias y saludos!

Comment: Buenas! :) Disculpa la confusión! es vb.net
Gracias!

Comment: Ahora sólo queda mostrarnos tu progreso par a ver cómo te ayudamos, dale, edita tu pregunta con toda la información que consideres útil y relevante para los que quieren ayudar :), saludos!!

Comment: Hola de nuevo! No creo que haya más que añadir, la pregunta es sencilla, que propiedad de un datagridview tengo que editar para que al maximizar la ventana ejecutando el programa se amplíe también el datagridview (la tabla) de una forma proporcional.

Comment: Pero... ¿Qué has hecho para lograr lo que te propones en tu pregunta?

Comment: Poner un datagridview en un form, el datagridview está compuesto por una tabla de una base de datos.

Comment: Hola Adrian, hasta donde tengo entendido los datagridview son de windows forms. Pero no me queda muy claro bien lo que intentas hacer solo por medio de comentarios, nos serviría mucho que editaras tu pregunta agregando tus partes del código del datagridview, de esa manera podremos ver con claridad como agrandarlo.

Comment: Hola de nuevo! :) Ya he añadido las imágenes y explicaciones que me pedíais, ante todo muchas gracias por vuestro interés!

Comment: Investiga sobre la propiedad Anchor del control.

Comment: Vaya! Ya veo que he hecho mal! Estaba seleccionando anchor right y down, he seleccionado todas y ahora se amplia proporcionalmente de forma automática.
Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Forms no tiene mecanismos demasiado buenos para manejar este tipo de problemas.

Lo que puedes hacer es recalcular el tamaño del DataGridView en los eventos `Resize` y `Shown` del Form.

Algo así:

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    ResizeControls()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
    ResizeControls()
End Sub

Private Sub ResizeControls()
    DataGridView1.Width = Width - 200
    DataGridView1.Height = Height - 150
End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Asier!

Answer (score 0):

Haz click sobre el grid y verás que aparece un triangulo, expandelo y seleccionas la opción de acoplar a su contenedor, al igual que la imagen que te muestro.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]